# How do I filter a history table for items that had a specific status but exclude that item if it also had another specific status

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, relational-database

In our SQL Server 2008 database, we have a one-to-many relationship between the "Jobs" table and the "History" table. Each time the status of the job is changed, we log the Status, date-time and Job ID into the History table.

I need to get all the Job ID’s where the  history  has a status = “Issued” **unless** the job history also has a status = “Revoked”.

If the history for a Job has a status = “Revoked”, but then at a **later date** has a status = “Issued” , it must be included in the results.

So based on the following mock up table and the rules above, the results that should be returned are FK_JobID’s 2 and 3.

```
DECLARE @History TABLE 
( 
    HistoryID   INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
    MaterStatus VARCHAR(300), 
    Updated     DATETIME, 
    FK_JobID    INT
)

INSERT INTO @History 
VALUES ('Issued','2015-09-09',1), 
       ('Revoked','2015-09-09',1),
       ('Issued','2015-09-09',2),
       ('Archived','2015-09-09',2),
       ('Issued','2015-09-09',3),
       ('Revoked','2015-09-09',3),
       ('Issued','2015-09-10',3),
       ('other','2015-09-09',4);
```

How do I write this query to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method of pulling the results using a `CTE` to get the most recent times a status was issued, and using a `NOT EXISTS` clause to filter out those that were revoked.

```
;With RecentStatuses As 
(
    Select  FK_JobId, MaterStatus, Max(Updated) Recent
    From    @History
    Group by FK_JobID, MaterStatus
)
Select  H1.FK_JobID
From    RecentStatuses  H1
Where   H1.MaterStatus = 'Issued'
And Not Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    RecentStatuses  H2
    Where   H2.FK_JobID = H1.FK_JobID
    And     H2.MaterStatus = 'Revoked'
    And     H2.Recent >= H1.Recent
)
```